# nigthtwatchjs skipping lines

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

i ve got an issue with, while using nightwatchjs ,  sometimes when i run test it skips all lines before waitForElementVisible and and is waiting for two minutes doing nothing and crashes, but its not always like that sometimes it performs normally, any solution????

```
        .setValue('#body', 'value')
        .click('#body')
        .pause(10000)
        .setValue('body', 'value')
        .click('#body')
        .waitForElementVisible('#body', 120000)
        .click('#body')
```

Comment: Can you please check the locator value for setValue. Where exactly are you setting the value ?

Comment: locator values are fine  there is no issues caused by them

Comment: Can you post the entire code and if any error that is showing up?